# "Run Selection" for cmd.exe

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am looking for some functionality similar to PowerShell's "Run Selection (F8)" whereby I can edit some text (preferably in Sublime Text 3) and "Run selection in cmd.exe" (rather than PowerShell).

Is there anything that enables this kind of functionality?

To be clear, when I am prototyping scripts I want to do it all in one file, and send a specific line or lines to cmd.exe.

Comment: I wouldn't mind being using *anything* that could execute batch commands in a "select this text + run it in cmd.exe" manner. I'd want to execute it via cmd.exe rather than PowerShell (for PowerShell, we have the very fine PowerShell ISE). If we could execute arbitrary lines of selected text in cmd.exe via Sublime Text's build system, that would work well.

Comment: Nevermind. It's really more a cmd.exe question.  While you could shell out and run `cmd /c <line of batch>` you run into the issue of session state going away between invocations.  And the CMD engine isn't hostable like PowerShell's and AFAIK there isn't an IPC mechanism to feed commands into CMD.exe.  OTOH I wonder if you could create a loop in CMD.exe looking for new BAT files, execute them and store the results in a separate file and delete the original bat file and then wait for another bat file to appear.

Comment: Thanks Keith, at the moment, a script in PowerShell ISE where every line is prefixed with "cmd /c" seems to be the closest. For IPC, perhaps I could have a python script which waits for commands and executes them via os.system() and passes back the results...